# need to create a script to extract html

Tags: html, scripting, automation, extract

I need to create a script that will extract html from a loaded page. I can manually download the html in the "network" tab of the javascript console in chrome but I'd like to have a more automated process and I have no idea where to start with this. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use almost anything to automate this - it really depends on your platform and what you have installed. I would check out wget http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/ and whatever shell scripting you have available.